# Persist checkboxes after search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a search form that searches through another a checkbox list. When I check a box then search through it, the checked boxes revert back to being unchecked. I think it is due to having to different forms and submitting the search.

How to persist the checks without it reverting after search? I am using form_tag to search the things in the form_for.

```
<div class="container" id="spacing">    
  <div align="left" class="row inline" >
    <%= form_tag interest_index_path, :method => :get, :id => 'myform', :remote => true do %>

        <p>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-7" id="one">
                <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>
            </div>
            <div id="two">
                <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
            </div>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>

    <%= form_for :interest, url: interest_index_path do |f| %>
        <div class="field form-group col-lg-12" >
            <br>

            <div class="row inline">
                <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
                    <div class="field">
                        <p><h4>
                            <%= f.check_box :interests, {:multiple => true}, subject.id, nil %>
                            <%= subject.name %>
                        </h4></p>
                    </div> 
                <% end %>
            </div>


            <p class="col-md-8" align="left"><%= f.submit "Save Schedule", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"%></p>
        <br>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your question's description because of your English :) but it looks like that you have such behaviour because you are using `form_tag`.

You can use `form_for`, create a search object and save your intermediate state of searching in a memory or in a session.

Comment: Sorry for english. I edited question. hopefully its understandable. What do you mean save the intermediate state of searching. how do you do this.